# Suppose $f(x_0) < x_0$, for a positive and monotone-increasing function $f$. Does it follow that $f'(x_0) < 1$

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f$ be a real-valued $C^{\infty}$ function that is positive ($f(x)>0$ for all $x \geq 0$), and also monotone non-decreasing ($f(y)>f(x)$ when $y>x$). Suppose that this functions satisfies
$$
f(x_0) \leq x_0
$$
for some special point $x = x_0 > 0$.

Can you derive a bound for $f'(x_0)$ at this point $x=x_0$? For example, does it follow that
$$
f'(x_0) \leq 1 \ ?
$$

Comment: Why would that be true?  Say $f(x)=\frac 1{10}e^x$.  Then $f(3)<3$ but $f'(3)>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-n}e^{nx}$ satisfies the hypothesis with $x_0=1$ and $f'(x_0)=n$ so no absolute bound can be found.